# airflow breeze init failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow, breeze

I followed the instructions to initialize breeze environment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/CONTRIBUTORS_QUICK_START.rst#setting-up-breeze

Seems like the image is built but failed to start.Something wrong with my environment?

Good version of docker 20.10.9.
Python version: 3.8

Backend: mysql

No need to rebuild the image: none of the important files changed

```
                           Use CI image.

                           Branch name:            main
                           Docker image:           ghcr.io/apache/airflow/main/ci/python3.8
                           Airflow source version: 2.3.0.dev0
                           Python version:         3.8
                           Backend:                mysql 5.7
```

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/mnt/c/Users/binglilun/source/repos/doowhtron/airflow/scripts/in_container/entrypoint_ci.sh" to rootfs at "/entrypoint" caused: mount through procfd: not a directory: unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with the entrypoint file you're trying to mount.  What do you get with `ls -l /mnt/c/Users/binglilun/source/repos/doowhtron/airflow/scripts/in_container/entrypoint_ci.sh` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed.
Key things for running breeze on my wsl environment are:

1. Upgrade to wsl2(my distribution is ubuntu)
2. checkout the source to ~/ instead of /mnt/c/
3. run docker daemon inside wsl2(not using docker destop)
4. enable wsl's network by setting /etc/resolv.conf(putting nameserver 8.8.8.8)
5. add "--network host" parameter to docker_v build(_build_images.sh), otherwise internet cannot be connected
6. install yarn and add "--ignore-engines" to yarn install (compile_assets.sh)

And breeze works for me now.